# Djoser is ignoring my Authenitcation Token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, djoser

I set up djoser and DRF's TokenAuthentication. It works perfectly for registering users, and i get a valid token returned. When I try to access /users/me or /token/logout with header:
Authorization: Token {token} (and the token itself in the body for good measure) I get the response Error 403: "Authentication credentials not provided."

I've tried making the request through axios and postman.

I made other accounts and tried their keys but I get the same result.
I've looked on the djoser docs but there is no help there, nor anywhere else, because it seems no one else has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my settings.py I had correctly figured DEFAULT_AUTHENITCATION_CLASSES and not DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES. Now it works.